# Jupyter Hub breaks connection on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I'm hosting Jupyter hub on a separate vm instance in Google Cloud and for some reason connection fails every time when I don't do anything there actively for about 15 minutes. And after that I had to relaunch server and rerun everything again.
Is there some kind of timeout that I could change or maybe it's some kind of an optimised mode of usage I could turn off? I tried increasing CPU memory but still the same thing happens all the time.

I pinged the external IP:

```
PING <EXTERNAL_IP> (<EXTERNAL_IP>) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from <EXTERNAL_IP>: icmp_seq=1 ttl=61 time=0.857 ms
64 bytes from <EXTERNAL_IP>: icmp_seq=2 ttl=61 time=0.390 ms
64 bytes from <EXTERNAL_IP>: icmp_seq=3 ttl=61 time=0.418 ms
64 bytes from <EXTERNAL_IP>: icmp_seq=4 ttl=61 time=0.363 ms
64 bytes from <EXTERNAL_IP>: icmp_seq=5 ttl=61 time=0.385 ms
64 bytes from <EXTERNAL_IP>: icmp_seq=6 ttl=61 time=0.429 ms
64 bytes from <EXTERNAL_IP>: icmp_seq=7 ttl=61 time=0.440 ms
64 bytes from <EXTERNAL_IP>: icmp_seq=8 ttl=61 time=0.352 ms
64 bytes from <EXTERNAL_IP>: icmp_seq=9 ttl=61 time=0.357 ms
64 bytes from <EXTERNAL_IP>: icmp_seq=10 ttl=61 time=0.396 ms
64 bytes from <EXTERNAL_IP>: icmp_seq=11 ttl=61 time=0.356 ms
64 bytes from <EXTERNAL_IP>: icmp_seq=12 ttl=61 time=0.594 ms
64 bytes from <EXTERNAL_IP>: icmp_seq=13 ttl=61 time=0.408 ms
64 bytes from <EXTERNAL_IP>: icmp_seq=14 ttl=61 time=0.424 ms
64 bytes from <EXTERNAL_IP>: icmp_seq=15 ttl=61 time=0.414 ms
64 bytes from <EXTERNAL_IP>: icmp_seq=16 ttl=61 time=0.390 ms
64 bytes from <EXTERNAL_IP>: icmp_seq=17 ttl=61 time=0.378 ms
64 bytes from <EXTERNAL_IP>: icmp_seq=18 ttl=61 time=0.350 ms
64 bytes from <EXTERNAL_IP>: icmp_seq=19 ttl=61 time=0.437 ms
64 bytes from <EXTERNAL_IP>: icmp_seq=20 ttl=61 time=0.384 ms
64 bytes from <EXTERNAL_IP>: icmp_seq=21 ttl=61 time=0.361 ms
64 bytes from <EXTERNAL_IP>: icmp_seq=22 ttl=61 time=0.340 ms
64 bytes from <EXTERNAL_IP>: icmp_seq=23 ttl=61 time=0.496 ms
64 bytes from <EXTERNAL_IP>: icmp_seq=24 ttl=61 time=0.361 ms
64 bytes from <EXTERNAL_IP>: icmp_seq=25 ttl=61 time=0.333 ms
```

Logs from the Serial port 1:

```
Jun 21 17:11:09 jupyterhub bash[28473]: [I 2021-06-21 17:11:09.542 SingleUserNotebookApp log:189] 200 GET /user/<MY_USERNAME>/metrics (<MY_USERNAME>@<EXTERNAL_IP>) 9.10ms
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub systemd[1]: Stopping /bin/bash -c cd /home/jupyter-<MY_USERNAME> && exec jupyterhub-singleuser --port=59331...
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]: [C 2021-06-21 17:13:52.335 SingleUserNotebookApp notebookapp:1978] received signal 15, stopping
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]: [I 2021-06-21 17:13:52.336 SingleUserNotebookApp notebookapp:2145] Shutting down 2 kernels
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]: [I 2021-06-21 17:13:52.438 SingleUserNotebookApp multikernelmanager:226] Kernel shutdown: d179550b-b0df-4889-8605-049d4ec59f70
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]: [I 2021-06-21 17:13:52.438 SingleUserNotebookApp multikernelmanager:226] Kernel shutdown: 7f2ab807-18b8-465e-b21b-fd9d82a7c3c7
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]: [I 2021-06-21 17:13:52.438 SingleUserNotebookApp notebookapp:2160] Shutting down 2 terminals
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]: [I 2021-06-21 17:13:52.439 SingleUserNotebookApp management:199] EOF on FD 12; stopping reading
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]: [I 2021-06-21 17:13:52.540 SingleUserNotebookApp management:362] Terminal 2 closed
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]: [I 2021-06-21 17:13:52.541 SingleUserNotebookApp management:199] EOF on FD 16; stopping reading
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]: [I 2021-06-21 17:13:52.641 SingleUserNotebookApp management:362] Terminal 1 closed
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]: Websocket closed
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]: Websocket closed
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]: Traceback (most recent call last):
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]:   File "/opt/tljh/user/bin/jupyterhub-singleuser", line 10, in <module>
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]:     sys.exit(main())
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]:   File "/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 254, in launch_instance
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]:     return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]:   File "/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 845, in launch_instance
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]:     app.start()
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]:   File "/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterhub/singleuser/mixins.py", line 571, in start
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]:     super().start()
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]:   File "/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 2362, in start
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]:     self.cleanup_terminals()
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]:   File "/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 2161, in cleanup_terminals
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]:     run_sync(terminal_manager.terminate_all())
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]:   File "/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/utils.py", line 370, in run_sync
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]:     return wrapped()
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]:   File "/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/utils.py", line 364, in wrapped
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]:     result = loop.run_until_complete(maybe_async)
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]:   File "/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 587, in run_until_complete
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]:     return future.result()
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]:   File "/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/terminal/terminalmanager.py", line 96, in terminate_all
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]:     await self.terminate(term, force=True)
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]:   File "/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/terminal/terminalmanager.py", line 85, in terminate
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]:     self._check_terminal(name)
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]:   File "/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/terminal/terminalmanager.py", line 113, in _check_terminal
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]:     raise web.HTTPError(404, u'Terminal not found: %s' % name)
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub bash[28473]: tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found (Terminal not found: 2)
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub systemd[1]: jupyter-<MY_USERNAME>.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub systemd[1]: jupyter-<MY_USERNAME>.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    Jun 21 17:13:52 jupyterhub systemd[1]: Stopped /bin/bash -c cd /home/jupyter-<MY_USERNAME> && exec jupyterhub-singleuser --port=59331.
```

Comment: When this issue occurs, it is possible to access the instance through SSH? 
It would be useful if you provide some logs of the jupyterhub service.
Could you use the `ping <EXTERNAL_IP>` command to see if there is any package loss?
Also, while the issue persist, could you check the Serial Port of the VM?

Comment: @Nahuel good point, I'll check if there's access through ssh, thanks!

Comment: @Nahuel I've added results of the ping command and the logs from serial port 1. Looks like there's a system process that halts jupyterhub which is weird.